# Perl $$var -- two dollar signs as a sigil?

Tags: perl

This seems like something I should be able to easily Google, Bing, or DDG, but I'm coming up completely empty on everything.

Basically, I'm tasked with (in part) rewriting a set of old Perl scripts. Not being a Perl programmer myself, there's definitely a learning curve in reading these scripts to figure out what they're doing, but I've hit an absolute brick wall with lines like this one:

```
$comment = $$LOC{'DESCRIPTION'};
```

Near as I can tell, the right-hand side is a dictionary, or more precisely it's getting the value referenced by the key `'DESCRIPTION'` in said dictionary. But what's with the "extra" dollar sign in front of it?

It looks suspiciously like PHP's [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but after scouring search engines, assorted StackExchange sites, and [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), I can't find any indication that Perl even *has* such a feature, let alone that this is how it's invoked. The most I've turned up is that '$' is not a valid character in a variable name, so I know `$$LOC` is not merely calling up a variable that just happens to be named `$LOC`.

What is this extra dollar sign doing here?

Comment: See the [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927) on PerlMonks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an alternative form of dereferencing.  Could (and honestly probably should) be written as:

```
$LOC->{'DESCRIPTION'};
```

You'll sometimes see the same with other all basic data types:

```
my $str = 'a string';
my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2);
my @array = (1..4);

my $strref = \$str;
my $hashref = \%hash;
my $arrayref = \@array;

print "String value is $$strref\n";
print "Hash values are either $$hashref{a} or $hashref->{b}\n";
print "Array values are accessed by either $$arrayref[0] or $arrayref->[2]\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between doing that and, say, this: `$script = $DEFAULT{SCRIPT};` (which, interestingly, is the very next line in the script I'm looking at)? That is, same thing but without (apparently, anyway) any dereferencing? Is this a logic error (assuming it's the content of the dictionary that's wanted, of course)?

Comment: If you want to access an entire array, you use `@array`.  Or an entire hash, use `%hash`.  However, to access an element of an array or hash, you must use `$array[3]` or `$hash{key}` respectively.  So in that next line, `%DEFAULT` is a plain hash, and `SCRIPT` is a key of that hash whose value is being assigned to `$script`.

Comment: Okay, now I'm back to not understanding the original bit, because I thought that's what we were doing there. I think I just need to sit down with a "Perl 101" book or something...

Comment: @Kromey A lot of this kind of information [comes witn Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/). Really you should read [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). If you need more help look at http://learn.perl.org/tutorials/ .

Comment: Nice article on dereferencing: http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html

Comment: I think the `$${}` notation predates the `$->{}`.  This may or may not tell you something about the age of the program or the author.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing is treating a scalar as the 'address' at which you can locate another variable (scalar, array, or hash) and its value.

In this case, $LOC{DESCRIPTION} is being interpreted as the address of another scalar, which is read into $comment.

In Perl,

```
my $str = 'some val';
my $ref = \$str;
my $val = ${$ref};
my $same_val = $$ref;
```

Comment: That is very wrong. There is a big difference between a *reference* and a *memory address*. Perl is not C, and there is no way of retrieving a variable given its location in memory. However you *can* take a *reference* to any Perl variable using the backslash `\` operator, and that reference can be stored in any scalar Perl variable. The original variable can be accessed by *dereferencing* any reference to it

Comment: I wanted to use the address metaphor because I thought it would be helpful; the OP seemed unclear in the follow-up about what references are for. But, you are correct, it isn't a memory address.  I think it's more literally a copy of the hash key to a definition dictionary entry? Edited my answer.