# Perl $$ (double dollar) sign -- what does it dereference?

Tags: perl

I saw the question on [Perl $$var -- two dollar signs as a sigil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619917/perl-var-two-dollar-signs-as-a-sigil) and that double dollar sign is used to dereference

I have this perl code

```
sub sock_initialize {

    my $sock  = q{};
    my $port  = q{};

    # $name running
    my $max_count   = 250;
    my $timeout     = 5;
    my $max_retries = 36;

    # Get a port for our server.
    $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Listen    => SOMAXCONN,    # listen queue depth
        LocalPort => 0,
        Reuse     => 1
    );

    die "Unable to bind a port: $!" if !$sock;

    $port      = $sock->sockport();
    my $ip = inet_ntoa( scalar gethostbyname( $HOST ));
    my $uid = (getpwuid( $> ))[2];
    my $queue = join(":", $ip, $port, $$, $uid);

    print sprintf("started on port $port ($$), SOMAXCONN=%d\n", SOMAXCONN);

    return $sock;
} ## end sub sock_initialize
```

from the above code, what does double dollar sign dereferencing? `my $queue = join(":", $ip, $port, $$, $uid);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Simply

Like under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and other *`POSIX`* [shell](/questions/tagged/shell): **`$$` is current *process id (PID)***

For `man perlvar`:

> ```
>   $PROCESS_ID
>   $PID
>   $$      The process number of the Perl running this script.  Though you can
>           set this variable, doing so is generally discouraged, although it can
>           be invaluable for some testing purposes.  It will be reset
>           automatically across "fork()" calls.
> ```

Nota: from `man perl`

> ```
> Reference Manual
>         perlsyn             Perl syntax
>         perldata            Perl data structures
>         ...
>         perldebug           Perl debugging
>         perlvar             Perl predefined variables
>         ...
> ```

And from `man POSIX`...

> ```
>    "getpid"
>           Returns the process identifier.  Identical to Perl's builtin
>           variable $$, see "$PID" in perlvar.
> ```